# Error creating jar file in eclipse export

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

When I run the project IDE it compiles fine and runs through IDE but when I export it as a jar file. I get `-fat java export: could not find class path entry` for my project folder location. I couldn't figure whats causing this issue. Suggestions and solutions are welcome.

```
  Exported with compile warnings: 
  Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
    Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for 'C:Users/sivap/OneDrive/Desktop/eclipse workspace/Eclipse Workspace PITCON - To Edit - Copy/Questron'
```

Comment: there might be some non existing jar added to the classpath refering to _C:Users/sivap/OneDrive/Desktop/eclipse workspace/Eclipse Workspace PITCON - To Edit - Copy/Questron_ location. Check and if required re add from a valid location or delete it from the class path entry

Comment: i checked it they all are needed to run the program otherwise they give an error. I am also getting duplicate entries in my classpath file and project file generated in the message but when i see in the folder the duplicates are not there.

Comment: i also got duplicate entry message for all the classes i have in my project and the previously working workspaces stoppped working which were working fine. anywhere to think about what would have happened

Comment: Your classpath is refering to some libraries that are required but it do not exist on the specified location. Delete all the  entries of duplicates and the libraries not in the directory and then add them again but this time they should refer to a valid location

Comment: This is what my classpath is like and if some libraries are not there then the project turns red and it wont run inside the IDE itself.

Comment: @AhmadQureshi i did what you said but im still having the issue.

Comment: @Siva Prashanth check out these two links https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm and https://www.java67.com/2014/04/how-to-make-executable-jar-file-in-Java-Eclipse.html

Comment: thank you what about duplicate classpath and project warning when i export the jar

Comment: @Siva Prashanth, hope you resolved the issue by this time! I too got the same issue. The fat file warning disappeared after removing "resources" and "properties" entries from User entries of Classpath tab of configuration setting (of 'Run as' / 'Debug as'). In your case, the entries causing the warning might be different.